# jQuery & the param element

Tags: javascript, jquery, xml, dom

Is it correct that this code

```
$('<param><div></div></param>')
```

produces this output?

```
[<param>, <div></div>]
```

whereas with most other tags (eg:section)

```
$('<section><div></div></section>')
```

produces

```
[<section>...</section>]
```

In other words, jquery seems to remove elements inside a param element and place them alongside it. I'm aware that you usually wouldn't be placing dom elements inside a param tag. But I'm using jquery to traverse a XML document, and have run into this issue.

What would the workaround be?

Comment: jQuery expects html not xml, in html `param` is a self closing tag and cannot have child elements so jQuery fixes that for you. The Workaround is to use XML parser.. I.E `jQuery.parseXML`

Comment: I don't think jQuery fixes anything, it's the use of `innerHTML` (jquery uses it). `document.getElementById('mydiv').innerHTML = '<param><div></div></param>'` have the same effect.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As I said in the comment, jQuery expects HTML not XML, in HTML `param` is a self closing tag and cannot have child nodes so jQuery fixes that for you.

You can try:

```
$( $.parseXML( '<param><div></div></param>' ) ).children()
```

Which gives:

```
[<param>...</param>]
```

Answer (score 1):

You should begin to create a valid XML document:

```
var xml ='<param><div></div></param>';
var xmlDoc = $.parseXML( xml );
```

Then you can work on this doc:

```
var $xml = $( xmlDoc );
```

Answer (score 0):

The tag PARAM is an auto-closing tag, it cannot contain other elements inside.µ

When applying `<param><div></div></param>`, it is fixed to `<param><div></div>` so you get two elements in the jquery object.

Same happens with `<input><div></div></input>` for instance.
INPUT is auto-closing and this results into `<input><div></div>`

I don't think that jQuery fixes it, it is simply because jQuery uses `innerHTML`.

```
document.getElementById('mydiv').innerHTML = '<param><div></div></param>';
// you'll get two child elements <param> + <div>
```